# How do you animate the creation of a widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, tkinter

I have a frame which appears and disappear when a button is pressed. I want the frame to have animation when it appears, as if expands from the button.

This is the code I have so far:

```py
button_state = False #checks state of button
def click():
    button_state ^= True #switches between True and False
    if button_state == True:
        frame.place(x=50, y=30, width=10, height=10)
    else:
        frame.place_forget() #makes frame disappear

frame = Frame(window, bg='lightblue')

button = Button(window, text="menu", command=click)
button.place(x=50, y=50, anchor=CENTER)
```

Is it possible to do such a thing in tkinter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for loop to resize the frame to simulate the expand effect:

```
def click():
  if frame.place_info():
    frame.place_forget()
  else:
    # show the frame below the button
    x, y = button.winfo_x(), button.winfo_y()+button.winfo_height()
    # assume the final size of the frame is 100x100
    for step in range(1, 11):
      frame.place(x=x, y=y, width=step*10, height=step*10)
      frame.update_idletasks() # update the frame
      frame.after(10) # sleep for a very short period
```